# Real analysis - proving inequality using concavity of function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I am struggling with deriving proof for the following lemma:

By the use of the concavity of the appropriate function that for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $ x+y =1 $ , prove that the following inequality holds:

$x^3 + y ^3 \geq (x^2 + y^2)^2$

Help/advices/solutions very appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

$x\cdot x^2+y\cdot y^2\geq(x\cdot x+y\cdot y)^2$. Does this make it clear which function you should take?

**EDIT**. Also the restriction should be that $x,y$ are non-negative, or the inequality is simply not true.

Comment: Yep, using function f(x):=x^2 (concave by determining 2nd derivative) and taking arguments x,y and constants x, 1-x=y. Thanks!